# IntelliJ - Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Tags: intellij-idea

Not able to start/boot IntelliJ given was installed with JDK 17, however I'm not able to start it because JVM incompatibility (JDK17=61.0, JDK11=55.0). So, I set JAVA_HOME to JDK 11, but IntelliJ doesn't take the JDK/JRE update. Also, neither idea.jdk nor idea64.jdk was found to delete them. Also, I tried setting up IDEA_JDK and IDEA_JDK_64 without success.
Any help I'd really appreciate it.
`C:\Users\nnn>"C:\Program Files\ideaIC-2022.3.2.win\bin\idea.bat"`